# How to remove spacing in HTML

Tags: html, css

I would like to get these two lines to stay together. https://prnt.sc/j6c1ks

Desired result: https://prnt.sc/j6c5qb

The problem is that when I manage to get my desired result the first radio button stops working. How would I stop it from breaking?

```css
.form-label {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.label-option {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-label">
  <input type="radio" name="authorisation" value="i-do-not"> Speedy fried chicken
  <br>
</label>
<label class="label-option"> Would you like it spicy?
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No
</label>
```

Comment: try `label { display: inline-block } ` for the lines you want to be on the same line

Comment: Yes, as Annapurna says - specifically add it to your: .label-option class (display: inline-block;)

Comment: I want it to be like this but the first button keeps breaking http://prntscr.com/j6c5qb

Comment: Can you be please more clear about your requirement

Comment: You should remove the `<br />` from your HTML and `display: flex;` from your CSS

Comment: I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Just remove `<br/>` from your HTML code

Comment: I did. The problem is when there is no spacing, the radio button stops working.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the problem is causing by `padding: 20px` in your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Change `display:flex` to `display:inline-flex`:

```css
.form-label {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.label-option {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-label">
    <input type="radio" name="authorisation" value="i-do-not"> Speedy fried chicken <br>
</label>
<label class="label-option"> Would you like it spicy?
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.label-option {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-label">
  <input type="radio" name="authorisation" value="i-do-not"> Speedy fried chicken
</label>
<label class="label-option"> Would you like it spicy?
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is causing by the CSS `padding: 20px`, after removing this, you won't need that `<br />` anymore.

```css
.form-label {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-label">
  <input type="radio" name="authorisation" value="i-do-not"> Speedy fried chicken
</label>
<label class="label-option"> Would you like it spicy?
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="no"> No
</label>
```

Comment: Before downvoting my answer, please take a close look at what OP actually asks about...

Answer (score 0):

HTML auto maticllay remove spacing  if you need to remove spacing keep all in inline elements like span b i or else change the styles of display values should be override with inline